# Overfull vbox due to subsection title placed too high in Warsaw theme in Beamer

Tags: beamer, boxes

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\title{a}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{b}

\subsection{c}

\begin{frame}{d}
e
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It gives an `Overfull \vbox (3.1309pt too high) has occurred while \output is active` message which is not surprising given how the slide looks like:

[image]

The relevant part zoomed:

[image]

So, for some reason, `c` (the subsection title) is placed too high. I have no idea what could have gone wrong with such a minimal example...

Here is the relevant part of the log file:

```
Overfull \vbox (3.1309pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
\vbox(11.3737+0.0)x182.09767
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\hbox(14.50461+0.0)x182.09767
..\vbox(14.50461+0.0)x182.09767
...\pdfcolorstack 0 push {1 g 1 G}
...\glue 1.50092
...\hbox(4.50278+2.00124)x182.09767
....\pdfstartlink(*+*)x* attr{/Border[0 0 0]/H/N/C[.5 .5 .5]} action goto name{Navigation2}
....\hbox(2.65184+0.0)x182.09767, glue set 161.89502fil
.....\glue 8.5359
.....\T1/cmss/m/n/6 c
.....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\glue 8.5359
....\pdfendlink
...\pdfcolorstack 0 pop
...\glue 1.50092
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.99876
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x182.09767, glue set 91.04884fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

My beamer is 2017/08/22 v3.43 (everything is up-to-date, MikTeX 2.9).

Comment: I tried with beamer_v3.40 and there the problem was not yet there - so some changes between then and now...

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the experiment! I'm running v3.43 (I'll update the post with this information).

Comment: The problem is somewhere in `beamerbasecolor.sty`

Comment: The problematic commit is: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/6d4bd9e3569d047030d6a325c363a74b43b492dc#diff-adb611a8e4bdf2c7a8b624e9c8b7ed4f

Comment: As a temporary fix, place https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/beecbb9640c4541d17fd188f15c9cd4f99921a29/base/beamerbasecolor.sty in your working directory

Comment: Can you make a bug report on https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues?

Comment: @samcarter Wow, that was fast. Thank you very much! Sure, I have already submitted a bug report as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update:** This [bug](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/415) has been fixed in [`beamer` v3.44](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/releases/tag/v3.44), the example now works correctly out of the box.

There seems to be a small bug/inconsistency with the definitions of `\insertsectionnavigation` and `\insertsubsectionnavigation`, the macros responsible for generating the headline:

In `\insertsectionnavigation`, we have ([`beamerbasenavigation.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty), ll. 735-755)

```
\def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{% [...]
     % [...]
     \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}}
```

while for `\insertsubsectionnavigation`, it is ([`beamerbasenavigation.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty), ll. 769-792)

```
\def\insertsubsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{%
      % [...]
      \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}\hfil}}}
```

Note that the `\hfil` is  outside the `\vbox` for `\insertsectionnavigation`, but inside it for `\insertsubsectionnavigation`.

If you fix the definition of `\insertsubsectionnavigation`, the warning vanishes and the headline is displayed correctly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen

\title{a}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\def\insertsubsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{%
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vskip0.5625ex%
      \beamer@currentsubsection=0%
      \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{}%
      \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{\ifnum##6=\c@part\ifnum##1=\c@section%
        \ifnum##2>\beamer@currentsubsection%
        \beamer@currentsubsection=##2%
        \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
        \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##2}%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{##6}%
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\beamer@link(##4){%
            \hbox to #1{\hskip0.3cm%
              \ifnum\c@subsection=##2%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}}%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}}%
              \fi\hfil\hskip0.3cm}}}%
        \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
        \box\beamer@tempbox\fi\fi\fi}%
      \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}} % FIXED
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{b}

\subsection{c}

\begin{frame}{d}
e
\end{frame}
```

[image: zoomed part of the headline with correctly aligned section and subsection]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is this solution preferable to the one provided by samcarter among the comments of the question?

Comment: @TamasFerenci I only saw the analysis after answering the question myself. IMHO the commit samcarter identified "unearthes" the bug described in this answer for the first time, as without  the `\@arrayparboxrestore`, it couldn't be seen before. Furthermore the commit was introduced to fix [issue 353](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/353), so I hope proceeding as described here is less likely to break other things.

Comment: Thanks, clear! Let's hope it'll be shortly a theoretical question, as they fix this bug.